# Why does not set ButtonFlat onClickListener?(Material Design Android Library)

Tags: android, button, material-design

Android studio ignores this line:

```
yesButtonFlat.setOnClickListener(this);
```

All code:

```
public class AddProductDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private ButtonFlat yesButtonFlat;

private TextInputLayout inputNameLayout;
private EditText inputName;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().setTitle("Добавление товара");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_product_dialog, null);

    inputNameLayout = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.input_layout_name);
    inputName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    inputName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputName));

    yesButtonFlat = (ButtonFlat) v.findViewById(R.id.yes_button);
    yesButtonFlat.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.yes_button:
            System.out.println("Нажата кнопка");
            dismiss();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ignores this line? Is your click event working?

Comment: No, my event does not work

Comment: Can you post your xml code too?

Comment: I make ButtonFlate public and it starts work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make ButtonFlate `public` and it starts work.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like you see below:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something in response to button click
    }
});
```

Check out the Guide [here!](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)